# Equal Average Partition DP using Python 2 VS Python 3

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I was using memorization to try to solve the [Equal Average Partition Problem](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/equal-average-partition/), somehow the solution that I came up with take a long time to solve the problem in [Python 2.x](https://repl.it/DJdT) but relatively fast in [Python 3.x](https://repl.it/DJci) 
I'm wondering whether anyone encounter something similar, and what are the reasons behind? Thanks

```
def avgset(A):
    if len(A) <= 1: return []
    A.sort()
    A = tuple(A) 
    idx = 0 
    curSum = 0
    curSize = 0
    dic = {}
    length = len(A)
    avg = sum(A)/float(length)
    minAry = sorted(recursive(A, idx, curSum, curSize, avg, dic), key=lambda x:len(x))[0]
    A = list(A)
    for itm in minAry: A.remove(itm)
    return [minAry, A]

def recursive(A, idx, curSum, curSize, avg, dic):
    if idx > len(A)-1: return None 
    if (idx, curSum, curSize) in dic.keys(): return dic[(idx, curSum, curSize)]
    if (curSum+A[idx])/ float(curSize+1) == avg:
        return [[A[idx]]]
    res1 = recursive(A, idx+1, curSum+A[idx], curSize+1, avg, dic) or []
    res2 = recursive(A, idx+1, curSum, curSize, avg, dic) or []
    res3 = []
    for itm in res1:
        tmp = [A[idx]]+itm
        if tmp not in res3:
            res3.append(tmp)
    for itm in res2:
        if itm not in res3:
            res3.append(itm)
    dic[(idx, curSum, curSize)] = res3
    return dic[(idx, curSum, curSize)]


A = [ 28, 10, 2, 44, 33, 31, 39, 46, 1, 24, 32, 31, 28, 9, 13, 40, 46, 1, 16, 18, 39, 13, 48, 5 ]
print (avgset(A))
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include both code samples here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one difference between python 2 and 3 that you are using. In line

```
if (idx, curSum, curSize) in dic.keys(): return dic[(idx, curSum, curSize)]
```

method `keys()` in python2 returns list of dict keys and in python3 returns iterator through keys (it was iterkeys() method in python2.) Note that method `keys()` is not needed since operator `in <dict>` will return result you want. So code

```
if (idx, curSum, curSize) in dic: return dic[(idx, curSum, curSize)]
```

works with same speed in 2 and 3.

It seems that operator `in <iterator>` is optimized in python3, if it is possible to evaluate it faster than to iterate through elements, like in `dict` or `set`.

Answer (score 0):

`something in dic.keys()` will be O(n) in Python 2 (membership in list) and O(1) in in Python 3 (membership in set). This accounts for observed difference in performance.

On [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.
>   If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and
>   hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not
>   treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For
>   set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base
>   class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

Consider using `something in dic`, which is O(1) in both Python 2.x and 3.x and is basically equivalent (unless you modify dict on the fly and want to freeze state of dict keys before modifying it)